# getting akka dead letters when using pipeTo between two actors

Tags: scala, akka, akka-actor

i have a use case in which i have a actor hierarchy

```
parent -> childABC -> workerchild
```

Now the worker child works and send its result to its parent(childABC which is a child of parent) and that child actor(childABC) send the result back to parent actor I am using `pipeTo` and getting dead letters here is my code

`parent` actor:

```
final case object GetFinalValue

class MyActor extends Actor{
  import context.dispatcher
  import akka.pattern.pipe
  val log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass)
  val myManageActor = context.actorOf(Props[ManagerMyActor],"Managemyactor")
  implicit val timeout = Timeout(ReadTimeIntervalValue.getInterval(), SECONDS)

  override def receive: Receive = {
    case GetFinalValue=>
      ask(myManageActor,GetValue).pipeTo(sender())

    case message =>
      log.warn(" Unhandled message received : {}", message)
      unhandled(message)
  }

}
```

`childABC` (acc to example I gave above)

```
final case object GetValue

class ManagerMyActor extends Actor{
  import context.dispatcher
  import akka.pattern.pipe
  val log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass)
  val myTokenActor = context.actorOf(Props[TokenMyActor2],"toknMyActor2")
  implicit val timeout = Timeout(ReadTimeIntervalValue.getInterval(), SECONDS)

  override def receive: Receive = {
    case GetValue=>
      ask(myTokenActor,CalculateValue).pipeTo(sender())
 
    case message =>
      log.warn(" Unhandled message received : {}", message)
      unhandled(message)
  }

}
```

`child` actor:

```
final case object CalculateValue

class TokenMyActor2 extends Actor{
  import context.dispatcher
  import akka.pattern.pipe
  val log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass)

  override def receive: Receive = {
    case CalculateValue=>
      val future = Future{ "get the string"
      }
      val bac = future.map{result =>
          sender ! result
      }//.pipeTo(sender())


    case message =>
      log.warn("Actor MyActor: Unhandled message received : {}", message)
      unhandled(message)
  }

}


def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    implicit val timeout = Timeout(ReadTimeIntervalValue.getInterval(), SECONDS)

    val myActor = system.actorOf(Props[MyActor],"myActor")
    val future = ask(myActor, GetFinalValue).mapTo[String]
    future.map {str =>
      log.info ("string is {}",str)
    }
```

Here are the logs:

```
[INFO] [akkaDeadLetter][01/12/2021 19:17:22.000] [api-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-5] [akka://api/deadLetters] Message [java.lang.String] from Actor[akka://api/user/myActor/Managemyactor/toknMyActor2#1239397461] to Actor[akka://api/deadLetters] was not delivered. [1] dead letters encountered. If this is not an expected behavior then Actor[akka://api/deadLetters] may have terminated unexpectedly. This logging can be turned off or adjusted with configuration settings 'akka.log-dead-letters' and 'akka.log-dead-letters-during-shutdown'.
[INFO] [akkaDeadLetter][01/12/2021 19:17:41.989] [api-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-7] [akka://api/deadLetters] Message [akka.actor.Status$Failure] from Actor[akka://api/user/myActor#1829301550] to Actor[akka://api/deadLetters] was not delivered. [2] dead letters encountered. If this is not an expected behavior then Actor[akka://api/deadLetters] may have terminated unexpectedly. This logging can be turned off or adjusted with configuration settings 'akka.log-dead-letters' and 'akka.log-dead-letters-during-shutdown'.
[INFO] [akkaDeadLetter][01/12/2021 19:17:41.996] [api-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-7] [akka://api/deadLetters] Message [akka.actor.Status$Failure] from Actor[akka://api/user/myActor/Managemyactor#-269929265] to Actor[akka://api/deadLetters] was not delivered. [3] dead letters encountered. If this is not an expected behavior then Actor[akka://api/deadLetters] may have terminated unexpectedly. This logging can be turned off or adjusted with configuration settings 'akka.log-dead-letters' and 'akka.log-dead-letters-during-shutdown'.
```

Please guide me where am I mistaken, or `pipeTo` should not be used like this? if so what should i do to make it work

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not sure if it's intended or not but `ask(myManageActor,GetValue).pipeTo(sender())` can be implemented as `forward`.

```scala
class MyActor extends Actor {
  lazy val myManageActor: ActorRef = ???

  override def receive: Receive = {
    case GetFinalValue =>
      myManageActor.forward(GetValue)
  }
}
```

`forward` is the same as `tell` but it preserves the original sender of the messages.

This can be applied to `MyActor` and `ManagerMyActor`.

In the case of `TokenMyActor2`, you should not use

```scala
future.map{ result =>
          sender ! result
      }
```

as it it breaks akka context encapsulation, as specified in [docs](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/actors.html#ask-send-and-receive-future)

> When using future callbacks, such as onComplete, or map such as
> thenRun, or thenApply inside actors you need to carefully avoid
> closing over the containing actor’s reference, i.e. do not call
> methods or access mutable state on the enclosing actor from within the
> callback. This would break the actor encapsulation and may introduce
> synchronization bugs and race conditions because the callback will be
> scheduled concurrently to the enclosing actor. Unfortunately there is
> not yet a way to detect these illegal accesses at compile time. See
> also: Actors and shared mutable state

You should instead rely on `Future(???).pipeTo(sender())`, which is safe to use with `sender()`.

After applying these changes, the code does work as expected

```scala
case object GetFinalValue
case object GetValue
case object CalculateValue

class MyActor extends Actor {
  private val myManageActor: ActorRef =
    context.actorOf(Props[ManagerMyActor], "myManageActor")

  override def receive: Receive = { case GetFinalValue =>
    myManageActor.forward(GetValue)
  }
}

class ManagerMyActor extends Actor {
  private val myTokenActor =
    context.actorOf(Props[TokenMyActor2], "toknMyActor2")

  override def receive: Receive = { case GetValue =>
    myTokenActor.forward(CalculateValue)
  }

}

class TokenMyActor2 extends Actor {
  import context.dispatcher

  override def receive: Receive = { case CalculateValue =>
    val future = Future { "get the string" }
    future.pipeTo(sender())
  }
}
```

```scala
implicit val timeout = Timeout(3, SECONDS)
implicit val system = ActorSystem("adasd")
import system.dispatcher
val myActor = system.actorOf(Props[MyActor], "myActor")
val future = ask(myActor, GetFinalValue).mapTo[String]
future.foreach { str =>
  println(s"got $str")
}
```

Produces `got get the string`.

As a final note, I'd advise not to use `ask` pattern within actors. The basic functionality of `ask` can be easily achieved with just `tell` and `forward`. Also the code is shorter and not overloaded with constant need of `implicit val timeout`

Answer (score 1):

Just to add on top of the great post by @IvanStanislavciuc. You already noticed that you lose the reference to the sender in futures. A simple solution for that will be to keep it up front.

It means that changing in `MyActor`:

```
ask(myManageActor,GetValue).pipeTo(sender()) // Won't work
```

into:

```
val originalSender = sender()
ask(myTokenActor,CalculateValue).pipeTo(originalSender)
```

In `ManagerMyActor`, Change:

```
ask(myTokenActor,CalculateValue).pipeTo(sender()) // Won't work
```

into:

```
val originalSender = sender()
ask(myManageActor,GetValue).pipeTo(originalSender)
```

And in `TokenMyActor2`:

```
val originalSender = sender()
Future{ "get the string" }.pipeTo(originalSender)
```

Code run at [Scastie](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/O7QRFLBMSvWI7tj774jLEw).

Comment: I think you're wrong. `pipeTo` is safe to be used as `pipeTo(sender())`. Even akka [examples](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.5/futures.html#use-the-pipe-pattern) use it like this

Comment: @IvanStanislavciuc, yes I am sure. I added a scastie link to prove it. I also remember along time ago when I took the akka-essentials course by Daniel this is what he said, and demodtrated: https://github.com/rockthejvm/akka-essentials/blob/master/src/main/scala/part6patterns/AskSpec.scala#L102

Comment: The example you posted is using `onComplete` of `Future` and indeed, you have to pre-reference `sender()` in such case. But `pipeTo` does not have such limitation.

Comment: @IvanStanislavciuc, Right. Anyhow it solves the question, so although I upvoted your solution, and I think it is more elegannt in some way, I'll leave it here.

Comment: Also, your Scastie has a problem. You have `case class GetFinalValue` but match it as `case GetFinalValue`. it should be `case GetFinalValue()`

Comment: @IvanStanislavciuc, I sent the same message at line 59. That is the reason it worked. Thanks for that comment. I took it from the code the original post. I've fixed that.